# Can't format my SSD anymore

Tags: partitioning, ssd, formatting, hardware-failure

I am not sure if my SSD is broken.

I tried to install Windows 7 on my SSD today and it somehow got stuck in the installation process.

After aborting the installation, I tried it again but I couldn't format it any more. I installed Windows on another HDD and it recognizes the SSD but I can't access it in any way.

I now booted into Linux with gparted and I can't create a partiton table `error while creating partition tablel`

It is listed in gparted and in my BIOS, but if I do `fdisk -l` it is not listed there.

Could it be possible that my SSD is dead?

What else can I try?

Comment: what SSD? More information might be useful here

Comment: It is an OCZ Vertex 2 60Gb ~1 1/2 years old

Comment: Yes, it sounds damaged.

Comment: Is there something else that I could try?

Comment: I had a problem too with an OCZ Vertex 2 120GB. It worked well for one week but then suddenly stopped working (It wasn't even detected by the BIOS). I've read of similar problems with OCZ SSDs in different forums so I recommend to anyone not to buy one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is something else you could try. There are three add-ons for GParted that are useful for reformatting an otherwise good disk that has a corrupted partition:

1. Device-Mapper Software RAID support tool (dmraid)
2. Guess PC disk partition table, find lost partitions (gpart)
3. Read/write NTFS driver for FUSE (ntfsprogs)

I don't know if it is possible to install these add-ons on the GParted Live USB, however it is certainly possible to select these add-ons for installation along with GParted in many Linux distributions, for example, Ubuntu. Or, if that is not possible to do in your Linux distribution, the GParted add-ons could also be installed separately.