# Unable to format 240GB SanDisk SSD after failed windows 7 install

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, ssd, formatting

My 240GB SanDisk SSD will not format. I am unable to do anything with it. I had windows 7 installed on it and attempted to do a fresh install of windows 7. An error occurred during the installation (I didn't think much of the error at the time, so I don't remember what it was exactly, I think it was something about missing install files). I attempted to start to install over and the SSD no longer showed up for the installation.

I connected the SSD to another windows 7 PC and could see the system reserved partition and the OS partition which had incomplete installation files on it.

Everytime I tried to format the SSD it hangs for a while, then it disappears until I restart.

I tried use diskpart in cmd prompt during the installation to clean the SSD but it hangs when I attempted to select it, then it disappears.

I also attempted to format it with Ubuntu, the SSD does the same thing, it hangs and then disappears.

I also tried to install Ubuntu to the SSD. The Ubuntu installer is unable to install to the SSD.

I don't have any idea of what exactly is wrong with the SSD at this point other than the partitions seem to be corrupted. I want to fix it and not have to buy a new SSD. Please let me know if you have any idea what is wrong and how to fix it.

Thanks.

Comment: You'll probably need to buy a new SSD. But before that, in a Ubuntu live session you can open GParted. Try creating a new partition table first (Device menu). What happens?

Comment: It fails if you do the "quick format" option too even? That should take a couple seconds to do as opposed to a "full format". You may want to run some disk diagnostic tools for your drive to determine its health.

Comment: I already tried using gparted to create a new partition, it didn't work. I also tried quick format in Windows and Ubuntu, neither worked.

Comment: Similar issue...https://superuser.com/questions/576058/cant-format-my-ssd-anymore?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

Your SSD has (1) corrupted metadata<sup>1</sup> and (2) a firmware bug<sup>2</sup> in recovering from corrupt metadata.  As a result, whenever the bad metadata is accessed, the firmware stops responding and the host controller marks the disk as disconnected.
In my experience, this is actually a far more common mode of SSD failure than actually wearing out the flash memory.

Using the manufacturer's "secure erase" tool may recover the disk, if it ignores the existing metadata and just rewrites valid metadata from scratch.  On the other hand if it is designed to read and use the existing metadata, the "secure erase" may also fail, in which case you need to RMA the drive to the manufacturer.

When this happened to me, I had data I wanted to save... I was able to use an external USB->SATA converter cable to attach it to another computer, that way I could power-cycle the drive and resume the copy operation where it stopped.

---

<sup>1</sup> For example, logical block mappings used for wear leveling and TRIM.  If power is lost while updating these, they can be left in a corrupt/inconsistent state.

<sup>2</sup> Not terribly surprising: Because the error-recovery routines are used infrequently, it's more likely for bugs to slip past testing.

Comment: Would the two causes you brilliantly pointed out also cause the *disappears until I restart*?

Comment: @MichaelBay: Yes, that's what you see when *the firmware stops responding and the host controller marks the disk as disconnected*.  As I noted from my own experience, you don't have to reboot the computer/reset the host controller, just power cycle the SSD itself.  That's hard if it's wired in internally, but easy if using a USB/SATA adapter case.

Comment: Thank you. It was just to assure the OP the SSD is still recoverable.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I wondered if it might be a firmware or metadata issue. I just wasn't sure what to do about it. I will try to find something from the manufacturer to possibly fix it.

Comment: I attempted to use the SanDisk SSD Dashboard program but it says no supported devices detected.      I found out that there is still 2 months on the 3 year warranty so I am attempting to RMA now.